# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC5 app, and in the HomeController, I have an ActionResult defined like this:

```
    public ActionResult BlogRSS()
    {
        var model = new BlogModel();
        string strFeed = "http://webmysite.com/feed";

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strFeed))
        {
            SyndicationFeed rssData = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
            model.BlogFeed = rssData;
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Then, for this ActionResult, I created a partial view named `BlogRSS`, which looks like this:

```
@model MyApp.Models.BlogModel

@{
    if (Model.BlogFeed != null)
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var post in Model.BlogFeed.Items.ToList().Take(3))
            {
                <li><a href='@post.Links.First().Uri' target='_blank'>@post.Title.Text</a></li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
}
```

And my model is defined simply like this:

```
public class BlogModel
{
    public SyndicationFeed BlogFeed { get; set; }
}
```

So, the point is that I want to call that partial view in my _Layout.cshtml file, but when the website opens I get the error message specified in the title. I guess it is not calling my `BlogRSS` method at all.  I'm calling it in the _Layout.cshtml like this:

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
       Blog
       <br />
       @Html.Partial("BlogRSS")
 </div>
```

How can I solve the problem, and make sure that the corresponding ActionResult is also called before rendering the View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're putting a call to a partial view which just renders the view without calling the controller and the model passed to that view is `null`.

There are couple ways how to fix this:

1) use `Action` instead of `Partial`

```
@Html.Action("BlogRSS", "Blog")
```

2) Define a base ViewModel which you will pass to the each view and put your feed into it.

Comment: The point is that I want to call it in _Layout.cshtml file. If I try Html.Action, then the page is not opening at all, it keeps loading.

Comment: @tett ah, I see the problem. Try using `return Partial(model)` in your action.